# Elasticsearch：Field [xxx] of type [keyword] is not supported for aggregation [sum]

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch version: 7.13

mappings:
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/index' -d '{"settings":{"number_of_shards":1, "number_of_replicas":1},"mappings":{"properties":{"uid":{"type":"keyword"}}}}'

aggregation:
curl -XPOST -H'Content-Type:application/json' http://127.0.0.1:9200/index/_doc/_search?pretty -d '{"aggs":{"total_uid":{"sum":{"field":"uid"}}}}'

error" : {

```
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Field [uid] of type [keyword] is not supported for aggregation [sum]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "data_times5",
        "node" : "fr_3CZpIQNuargbfraWzPg",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "Field [uid] of type [keyword] is not supported for aggregation [sum]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "Field [uid] of type [keyword] is not supported for aggregation [sum]",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Field [uid] of type [keyword] is not supported for aggregation [sum]"
      }
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
```

Why such an error has occurred?

Comment: For sum field must be numeric type . You are probably trying to sum document Ids, if these are numeric values. you should create another field of same values with type  integer. You elastic version also appears to be quite old(<7)